# Docker не может получить контейнер

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Команда docker run hello-world висит, через неск. минут отваливается по таймауту с сообщением:

> docker: Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 408 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "`<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n\n`".

ОС Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 18:34:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 18:34:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

С версией 1.10 было то же самое.
MTU 1500 на всех интерфейсах.

Где копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если проблема (из-за провайдера) с [pmtu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery), то обычное средство решения — уменьшение *mtu* на сетевом интерфейсе, через который осуществляется связь с интернетом:

```
$ sudo ip l s dev имя-интерфейса значение-mtu
```

попробуйте уменьшить до 300 (ниже 300, насколько помню, уже нет смысла понижать). если поможет — постепенно увеличивайте, чтобы найти максимальное «рабочее» значение.

Comment: Спасибо, мне помогло! На роутере в настройках wan у меня стоит 1436 (и нет возможности изменить). Я выставил на своём wlan0 mtu на 8 меньше - sudo /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 mtu 1428 up, и всё заработало.